# Multiple columns in one single row mysql

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

## My returned query looks like this

| Name | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 |  |  |
| John |  | 3 |  |
| John |  |  | 5 |
| Ronn | 11 |  |  |
| Ronn |  | 9 |  |
| Ronn |  |  | 7 |

but I want them to be in a single row that looks like this, what functions should I use?

| Name | Type 1 | Type 2 | Type 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 1 | 3 | 5 |
| Ronn | 11 | 9 | 7 |

## # # Here's my query

```
SELECT c.name, 
       if(t.type = A, SUM(t.amount), "") AS Type 1,
       if(t.type = B, SUM(t.amount), "") AS Type 2,
       if(t.type = C, SUM(t.amount), "") AS Type 3
FROM 
       customer AS c,
       transaction as t

WHERE
       c.id = t.id
       AND t.type IN ("A", "B", "C")

GROUP BY c.id, t.type
```

Comment: This can me done with an aggregate. Look up how to use `GROUP BY` in a SQL query and you’ll find your answer 

Comment: Or, if you are already using GROUP BY, show us your query so that we could point to you what you need to correct in it to achieve the desired output.

Comment: @AndriyM check post again, i've added my query.

Comment: That can't seriously be the real query producing the first output in your question.  Your `type` column appears to be a string column, and yet you are applying `SUM` to it and somehow getting non-zero results like 1 or 5 or 9.  Still, in general the approach here is to remove `t.type` from `GROUP BY` and put the aggregate function (be it `SUM` or whatever) *around* the `IF()`.

Comment: @AndriyM ops my mistake. It is supposed to be t.amount

Comment: See the tag I added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly a job for StackOverflow. That said …

```
SELECT c.name, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'A' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) as `Type 1`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'B' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) as `Type 2`,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t.type = 'C' THEN t.amount ELSE NULL END) as `Type 3`
  FROM customer AS c INNER JOIN transaction as t ON c.id = t.id
 WHERE t.type IN ('A', 'B', 'C')
 GROUP BY c.name;
```

This is the query you are looking for.